# JQuery Autocomplete does not show all the results

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am facing the below issue all day and would appreciate any advice.

I am writing JQuery autocomplete and it shows only partial results but not all the results from arraylist.

When I debug in customFilter function, I see `array` contains expected string in each row and `term` has the correct input data from textbox.

```
function customFilter(array, terms) {
    arrayOfTerms = terms.split(" ");
    var term = $.map(arrayOfTerms, function (tm) {
         return $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(tm);
    }).join('|');
   var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
       return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};

$( "#frmCode" ).autocomplete({
  multiple: true,
  mustMatch: false,
  minLength: 2,
  source: function (request, response) {
    response(customFilter(
    availableCode, request.term));
  }
});
```

I tried

```
var a = $.grep(autoData, function(value){
  var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");
  return matcher.test(term);
});
```

but it did not work either. May I know what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");
```

to

```
var matcher = new RegExp("" + term, "i");
```

and it is working now.

```
console.log("result - " + matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value));

console.log("value - " + value)
```

shows expected result as verification  as well.