# Escaping single quotes in VB script >> Java script

Tags: javascript, vbscript, escaping, str-replace, single-quotes

I have a classic ASP which is coded in VB script and it also has Java script code in the script tag.

VS Script has an array and some row contains a single quote. And this VB Script array is being passed to Java script. As some string values contains single quotes, the webpage does not work after the string is passed to Java script.

I tried to escape single quotes in VB script before passing to Java Script

```
Dim escapeInvalidString    
escapeInvalidString = Replace(objrec.Fields("Name"), "'", """chr(39)""")
vbStr = escapeInvalidString
```

Also tried

```
escapeInvalidString = Replace(objrec.Fields("Name"), "'", "''")
```

I tried in Java script without escaping in VB Script as well

```
var jsStr ="";    
jsStr = '<%= vbStr %>'.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

Also tried this.

```
jsStr = '<%= vbStr %>'.jsStr.replace(/\"/g,'\\"');
```

I have a feeling that I need to escape single quotes in VB Script parts but the above did not work. Any tips would be very appreciated.

Comment: The VB code needs to output strings where embedded `'` characters are changed to `\'`, but your code seems to try to change them to `''`. (You can't wait to do the replacement in JS because by then you've already got syntax errors from strings that weren't escaped properly.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you for your response. I understand the different between what I tried to do and wanted to do now. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3607h29(v=vs.84).aspx) on the server-side and [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape#Examples) on the client-side. They are compatible and both are Unicode (well, UCS-2 in fact) compliant.

```js
var jsStr = unescape('<%= Escape("foo ' bar '") %>');
```

Comment: Why would you need to unescape? Just have the server-side code generate valid JS in the first place.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Thank you so much for your quick response. I made the change and it is working now. It is much simpler than what I was coding!

Comment: I am facing another issue on the same piece of ASP. Could you take a look only if you get time please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090558/jquery-autocomplete-does-not-show-all-the-results

Comment: @nnnnnn Generating a valid JS string requires hard work. That string must be safe. There could be line-breaks, special characters, literals, and most importantly evil codes. Escape / Unescape makes handling these easy. That's why I recommended this for ASP Classic w/ VBScript, an old platform obsoleted long time ago. If there's a library to sanitize JS strings on the server side, it would definitely be a better choice.

Comment: @Chrissa You're welcome. I'll look in your answer in my spare time. But seems like you need a tour to understand how Stackoverflow works. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Kul-Tigin I recently move to the front-end side and start using stackoverflow actively. I'm sorry if this was inappropriate approach. I will check the link. Thank you again!